# Easy access control to Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

I need to control access to my whole Ruby on Rails app, allowing only some selected users to see it while it's under development.

I'm not looking into a full authentication system, but something much simpler, where I can add an email address to a restricted-users list, send an email to it and let that user see the app, rejecting any other user.

I have tried to use the WWWhisper add-on in Heroku (the app is hosted there) as it's just what I would need, but it doesn't seem to be available outside of the US.

I think I will have to build it myself, but, before, I wanted to make sure that there isn't a simpler solution already available. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to want to add an Auth system for regular users at some point anyway, so you could add it now to limit access to the other devs.  In a lot of ways this is actually easier than writing something simple yourself, and then you won't need to ditch it and replace it later.

Comment: We're already using devise for standard authentication for the user types of the app, but i need to restrict access to even those authentication pages, so that only the people I explicitly allow can even get to the signup/login pages of the app.

Comment: Ah.  probably basicauth then. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Comment: Actually my answer below is the simplest answer, i think, and nicer than basicauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your access requirement is "having got an invitation email" then i think your simplest option is to have something like this

```
#in application.rb

before_filter :require_invite

protected
  def require_invite
    session[:invite_token] ||= params[:invite_token]
    unless session[:invite_token] == "<SOME SECRET KEY STRING>"
      redirect_to external_home_path and return
    end
  end
end
```

where `external_home_path` is some holding page for people who haven't got an invite, which says "Sorry you need an invite token blah blah".  You'll need to add this to the controller which handles the external home page, to avoid a circular redirect.

```
skip_before_filter :require_invite, :only => [:external_home]
```

Then you just need to send people an invite with a link like

```
http://example.com?invite_token=<SOME SECRET KEY STRING>
```

Obviously this isn't very secure but it's as secure as the "have i seen the email" criterion.

When you go live you can take this before_filter out.

Comment: Thanks Max, much appreciated, I think your answer is a good quick and simple solution for now.